# Defining multipart nested node with pictogram in north east corner

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to set up a node style that allows me to draw nodes like UML2 components diagrams, etc.

What I consider as a good idea for a syntax is:

```
\node {node}
    child{
         \node {other node}
    };
```

which is good, but I don't know how I can format this as rectangle, and place component symbols in the north east corner.

`tikz-uml` is not what I need, because it has an interface that is different than that of TikZ.

I've also tried to typeset it as:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
      \node[draw, execute at begin node = \begin{tikzpicture}, execute at end node = \end{tikzpicture}] at (-1,-1)
      {
         \node[draw,minimum width=20pt] at (-1,1) {node};
      };
      \node[draw] at (1,1)
      {
         \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[draw,minimum width=20pt] at (-1,1) {node};
         \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But there is a problem with nested nodes.

**The problem is that `execute at begin node` affects sub-nodes.**

---

I'm searching for something that allows me easly to make a node that is a UML2 component. No matter how, but I want to create it writing:

```
\node [umlcomponent] ...
```

or by

```
\umlcomponent[fill=red...] at (2,2) {damn UML component} ...
\draw (1,1) umlcomponent {damn uml component} ...
```

So there is my question:
**How can I define a custom TikZ command/macro/something that allows me to reach the syntax**
[Nested node class with pictogram decoration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87955/23579)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`). For your target, I would consider first if [TikZ-UML](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en) satisfies your needs.

Comment: May I ask you why TikZ-UML is not what you need? Also nesting tikz pictures in this context is kind of looking for trouble since most of your nodes won't inherit/inherit wrong options.

Comment: Instead of `execute at begin node` and `\begin{tikzpicture}` inside of the node, you could just write `\tikz\node …`, which is at least shorter. On that node: Why do you want to place a node inside another one anyway? Do you want a `double` border? Do you want to `fit` an outer node around the inner one? What is your graphical goal here? The image of your linked question does look like something for a multi-part node.

Comment: No real reply to the points above: 'unclear'.