# Nested node class with pictogram decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees, tikz-styles

I'm wondering how can I define custom TikZ node class `mynode` thats allows my to use following syntax:

```
\node [mynode,fill=yellow!40] {component}
      \child{
           \node [mynode,fill=yellow!40] {subcomponent}
      };
```

and gives following result:

[image: resoult]

Comment: `\draw mynode` is very difficult to make work.  Would `\draw node[mynode]` be okay?

Comment: So, @AndrewStacey do you know how to do it, using `\draw node[mynode]` syntax, because it will be of course enough.

Comment: You need to add a little more information.  What types of input do you want?  How many levels of nesting?

Comment: @AndrewStacey as you should see there should be of course infinite levels of nesting. What do you mean by saying types of input? I think that answer to it is that i want just simple text input.

Comment: Is the "code" in your question what you would like to write in your document?

Comment: Yes it is, @AndrewStacey. Do you think it could be reached by this, or it should be done in other way?

Comment: @AndrewStaceydo you know answer to my question, or some sulution that allows me to do it.  If not try answer to it http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88011/23579

Answer (score 7):

This probably would also be doable with a tree (`child`) but the first thing that got to my mind was a `rectangle split` node.

The left node mimics what I tried to achieve and is even not good because the inner node is used to calculate the bounding box (this is the reason I had to set `border=8pt` for the `standalone` class).

So to have a node-node with `<Outer Name>` and `<Inner Name>` you just have to write the usual:

```
<path> node[subcomponent=<Inner Name>] {Outer Name} <path>;
```

or

```
\node[subcomponent=<Inner Name>] {Outer Name};
```

The inner node has an extra `fill=none` added which consequence can be seen if the `opacity` key is used.

*If such little icon in the upper right corner should appear too, you should provide either code or an example for it as it will probably require a little effort on the `\tikzlastnode` side.*

### Code

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{
    mycomponent/.style={
        draw,
        fill=yellow!40,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split allocate boxes=2,
        rectangle split empty part height=4ex,
        rectangle split empty part width=0ex,
    },
    subcomponent/.style={
        mycomponent,
        measure me={#1},
        rectangle split every empty part={},% resets empty-part macro
                                            % see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88700
        rectangle split empty part height={max(4ex,\qrrInnerNodeHeight)},
        rectangle split empty part width=\qrrInnerNodeWidth,
        append after command={
            node[mycomponent,fill=none,anchor=south west] at (\tikzlastnode.two) {#1}
        }
    },
    measure me/.code={%
        \global\sbox0{\tikz[baseline=0pt]\node[mycomponent,anchor=south]{#1};}%
        \edef\qrrInnerNodeWidth{\the\wd0}%
        \edef\qrrInnerNodeHeight{\the\ht0}%
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mycomponent] {%
    Component
    \nodepart{two}
    \tikz{\node[mycomponent] {Subcomponent};}
    };
    \node [xshift=3cm,subcomponent=Subcomponent] (t) {Component};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: +1: This is probably a bit fragile in the long end, but I certainly do like the `measure me` trick :-)

Comment: But it wont provide syntax that i prsented