# TikZ rectangle split parts with fixed height

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I was wondering if there is a way to set the height of rectangle split parts. I had no luck finding something in the pgfmanual. (Using `\phantom` seems just like a quickfix.)

Here is an example to illustrate my problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzstyle{data}=[rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,draw,text centered]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

    \node [data]                (A)    {data \nodepart{second} \phantom{null}};
    \node [data, right of=A]    (B)    {data};
    \node [data, right of=B]    (C)    {data \nodepart{second} null};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Result of the example.]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Does `rectangle split empty part height` (page 452 in the manual) do what you want?

Comment: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Nearly, now I can set the height of empty parts, but I'd like to have the same height for every (in my case) second part, with or without content. [Sidenote: in my version of the manual it is page 509]

Comment: The reply by @Alain Matthes to a different question might be useful for you as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54252/minimum-height-in-split-rectangle

Comment: @PeterJansson I was hoping one could avoid a macro, which needs to be put everytime in there, when i want the specific format. Instead an option would be nicer, once defined in the preamble. But I think I'm going to use Alain Matthes solution, so thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following solution is a compromise between `\nodepart{second} \hphantom{null}` (or an extra macro) and the condition that even not-empty parts have an specified width.

The style `data+` takes one mandatory argument and sets the dimension of empty parts to the dimension of its argument.

In your example you would need `data+=null`. Of course, if the actual content of the second part of the last node changes, you would have to change the argument given to `data+` (though this could be a macro too).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzset{
    data/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        text centered,
    },
    data+/.style={
        data,
        rectangle split every empty part={},% resets empty-part macro (explanation below)
        rectangle split empty part width=\widthof{#1},
        rectangle split empty part height=\heightof{#1},
        rectangle split empty part depth=\depthof{#1},
    },
}
\newcommand{\data}{data \nodepart{second} \phantom{null}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node [data+={null}]        (A)    {data};
    \node [data, right of=A]    (B)    {\data};
    \node [data, right of=B]    (C)    {data \nodepart{second} null};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Excursus: `-1ex`

The definition of the `data+` style was previously

```
data+/.style={
    data,
    rectangle split empty part width=\widthof{#1}-1ex,
    rectangle split empty part height=\heightof{#1},
    rectangle split empty part depth=\depthof{#1},
},
```

The OP rightly asks

> [W]hy do you have to subtract `1ex` from the width?

PGF/TikZ has one special macro that is inserted for an empty node-part if `/pgf/rectangle split ignore empty parts` is `false`(which seems to be the default contrary to the PGF manual), otherwise we wouldn’t even get a box.
The name of this macro is `\pgf@lib@sh@rs@every@emptypart` (for short: empty-part macro).

One would expect that PGF stores away the lengths given to `rectangle split empty part <width|height|depth>` keys and does not build this macro with the latest dimensions until it is needed. But this is not the case.
Every time `rectangle split empty part <width|height|depth>` is used a rule of the given width, height or depth is created and *added*  to the empty-part macro (all other length parameters of that rule are `0pt`, meaning they are invisible (e.g. `\strut`)).

The problem arises that rules (even invisible ones) are getting stacked horizontally. Rules with a height or depth do not get stacked vertically so they don’t accumulate extra height/depth, but rules with a width (horizontal rules) accumulate.

But wait! We only used those keys once! Yes, but no.
As a matter of fact they are used once before, namely during the initialization.
The file [`pgflibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex) reads on lines 370, 378 and 386:

```
rectangle split empty part width=1ex,%  line 370
rectangle split empty part height=1ex,% line 378
rectangle split empty part depth=0ex,%  line 386
```

When we start we have a square box of `1ex × 1ex`. If we add a vertical rule of `2ex` we get a box of `1ex × 2ex`, but if we add a horizontal rule of `2ex` we get a box of `3ex × 1ex`.

### A picture worth than thousand words?

I constructed an example, where

- the initial box is empty:

  ```
  \def\pgf@lib@sh@rs@every@emptypart{}% clean slate
  ```
- and the rules have actually a “width” (orthogonal to its “length”), i.e. a horizontal rule has a height (actually a height and a depth so that the middle of the line lies on the baseline), and a vertical rule has a width.

#### Not-MWE

`rs width` is a short-cut for `rectangular split empty parts width`, the same holds for `rs height` and `rs depth`.

```
\node[rectangle split ignore empty parts=false]                                          (a) {a};
\node[right of=a,  rs width =  1ex]                                                      (b) {b};
\node[right of=b, rs height =  3ex]                                                      (c) {c};
\node[right of=c,  rs depth = .5ex]                                                      (d) {d};
\node[below of=a,   rs width = 1ex,  rs width = \widthof{null}]           [yshift=-.5cm] (e) {e};
\node[right of=e,  rs height = 1ex, rs height = 2ex, rs height = .5ex]                   (f) {f};
\node[right of=f,   rs depth = 1ex,  rs depth = 2ex,   rs depth = 3ex]                   (g) {g};
\node[right of=g,   rs width = 1ex,  rs depth = 2ex,  rs height = 1ex, rs width = 2.5ex] (h) {h};
```

#### Output

The rules are:

- baseline: black
- horizontal (`width`): red
- vertical (`height`): green
- vertical (`depth`): blue

[image]

### Is there a better solution?

Two come to mind:

1. instead of subtracting hard-coded `1ex` we could subtract the current actual width

   ```
   rectangle split empty part width=\widthof{#1}-\widthof{\pgf@lib@sh@rs@every@emptypart}
   ```

   which would work quite okay as long as its content is not wider than `#1`.
2. Overwriting the empty-part macro.

There is a undocumented key `rectangle split every empty part` that is not used once in PGF and TikZ. Its definition is

```
rectangle split every empty part/.store in=\pgf@lib@sh@rs@every@emptypart
```

We cannot do `rectangle split every empty part={\phantom{null}}` because TikZ switched to a `\nullfont` that swallows everything. (Have you ever tried to just write something in a `tikzpicture` environment?). This is the same reason, I used `calc`’s `\<dimen>of` macros, they escape this cleverly.

We could fill this empty part macro with rules (not again!) overwriting any existing content, but then we could just use our old solution without `-1ex` by just removing any content.

#### Code

```
\tikzset{
    data+/.style={
        data,
        rectangle split every empty part={},% resets empty-part macro
        rectangle split empty part width=\widthof{#1},
        rectangle split empty part height=\heightof{#1},
        rectangle split empty part depth=\depthof{#1},
    },
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Just out of curiosity: why do you have to subtract `1ex` from the width?

Comment: @ChristianR. Please see the lengthy addition to my answer. Hopefully my explanation is helpful.

Comment: @ChristianR. I have updated my solution with a better alternative by emptying the macro for the empty node-parts.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, I hope this answer will get the attention it desrves. :-)

Answer (score 7):

After trying out the suggestions in the comments to my question, I found it the easiest to stick with my first attempt using `\phantom`, so here how it lookes in code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzstyle{data}=[rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,draw,text centered]
\newcommand{\data}{data \nodepart{second} \phantom{null}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node [data]                (A)    {\data};
    \node [data, right of=A]    (B)    {\data};
    \node [data, right of=B]    (C)    {data \nodepart{second} null};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: Output]

I needed `data \nodepart{second} \phantom{null}` a couple of times, therefore I thought it would be nice to define an own command for this, which might seem like a bit much in the example, but for the real application it was very useful. Have a look:

[image: List]

I post this for it may help someone with a similar problem.