# Typesetting classical data structures in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, data-structures

During this [discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88258/tikz-rectangle-split-parts-with-fixed-height) an example image generated with TikZ was given by Christian R. but no code was provided:

[image]

It would be great to have the code snippet that implements it, because I think it has the basic pieces to typeset the most common data structures found in imperative languages.

Comment: [related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45376/tikz-library-for-computer-science/45381#45381)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I guess I can help. `:-)`

**Code**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}
\newcommand{\data}{data \nodepart{second} \phantom{null}}

\tikzstyle{ptr}  = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{head} = [rectangle, draw, text height=3mm, text width=3mm, text centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{data} = [rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw, text centered, minimum height=3em]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]

    \node[head, label=below:head] (head) {};
    \node[data, right of=head]    (A) {\data};
    \node[data, right of=A]       (B) {\data};
    \node[data, right of=B]       (C) {\data};
    \node[above of=C,head,node distance=2cm,label=above:prev]   (prev){};
    \node[data, right of=C]       (D) {\data};
    \node[above of=D,head,node distance=2cm,label=above:curr]   (curr){};
    \node[data, right of=D]       (E) {\data};
    \node[data, right of=E]       (last) {data \nodepart{second} null};

    \draw[fill] (head.center)   circle (0.05);
    \draw[fill] (prev.center)   circle (0.05);
    \draw[fill] (curr.center)   circle (0.05);

    \path[ptr]  (head.center) --++(right:7.5mm)  |- (A.text west);
    \draw[fill] ($(A.south)!0.5!(A.text split)$) circle (0.05);
    \draw[ptr]  ($(A.south)!0.5!(A.text split)$) --++(right:10mm) |- (B.text west);
    \draw[fill] ($(B.south)!0.5!(B.text split)$) circle (0.05);
    \draw[ptr]  ($(B.south)!0.5!(B.text split)$) --++(right:10mm) |- (C.text west);
    \path[ptr] (prev) -- (C);
    \draw[fill] ($(C.south)!0.5!(C.text split)$) circle (0.05);
    \draw[ptr]  ($(C.south)!0.5!(C.text split)$) --++(right:10mm) |- (D.text west);
    \path[ptr] (curr) -- (D);
    \draw[fill] ($(D.south)!0.5!(D.text split)$) circle (0.05);
    \draw[ptr]  ($(D.south)!0.5!(D.text split)$) --++(right:10mm) |- (E.text west);
    \draw[fill] ($(E.south)!0.5!(E.text split)$) circle (0.05);
    \draw[ptr]  ($(E.south)!0.5!(E.text split)$) --++(right:10mm) |- (last.text west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result (even though it can be seen already in the question)

[image]

I'm pretty sure the code can be simplified, so improvements are welcome.

Comment: Instead of explicit circles try `\tikzstyle{ptr}  = [draw, -latex',postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0 with {\fill circle(0.05);}}}]`